# When is $R[x]$ a Domain?

Tags: ring-theory

Is there a connection between $R$ having zero divisors and $R[x]$ having zero divisors?

Answer (score 5):

$R[x]$ is a domain iff $R$ is a domain.

Indeed, every zero divisor in $R$ is a zero divisor in $R[x]$.

Conversely, if $fg=0$ in $R[x]$, then $f_m g_n=0$ in $R$, where $m=\deg(f)$ and $n=\deg(g)$.

Comment: What it means to zero divisor?

Comment: @PrasadPatil So you asked the question above without knowing what the words meant?

Answer (score 2):

Definition: $R$ is a domain if and only if $$\forall a,b\in R, ab=0\Rightarrow a=0\text{ or } b=0$$

Theorem: $R[x]$ is a domain if and only if $R$ is a domain.

Proof: $R\subset R[x]$, so the only if direction is trivial. For the other direction, let $p(x),q(x)$ be nonzero polynomials such that $p(x)q(x)=0$. A polynomial is identically zero iff all of its coefficients are $0$. Consider the leading terms of $p(x),q(x)$ respectively. Say they are $ax^n$ and $bx^m$. Write $p(x)=ax^n+p'(x)$ and $q(x)=bx^m+q'(x)$. Then $$p(x)q(x)=abx^{n+m}+ax^nq'(x)+bx^mp'(x)+p'(x)q'(x)$$ for this polynomial to be identically zero, $abx^{n+m}$ would have to be $0$, since the degree of the rest of the terms is strictly less than $n+m$. This would mean $ab=0$, but $a,b\neq 0$ by definition of leading coefficient, and so they are zero divisors of $R$.